# Can we pause an azure devops agent job and wait for callback

Tags: callback, azure-devops

I want to pause an agent job and resume it after getting callback notification.
I'm able to achieve this in server job by using "Invoke Rest Api" task. I would like to see a similar task for agent jobs.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to see a similar task for agent jobs

I am afraid that there is no existing agent job task could meet your requirements.

Here is a method to add call back notification to Agent job, you can refer to it.

1.Create an environment in **Pipeline -> Environments**. Then add the **“Invoke REST API”** as check method.
[image: Environment]

2. Reference this environment in Yaml. You could refer this doc about [Environment in Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#target-an-environment-from-a-deployment-job)
3. The pipeline will be paused until a call back notification is received